# How do I display the required information from JSON with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

How do I echo the information from my JSON object. The code is shown below;

```
array(20) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (15) {
    ["team_id"]=>
    int(10260)
    ["home"]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (7) {
      ["played"]=>
      int(15)
    }
    ["away"]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (7) {
      ["played"]=>
      int(15)
    }
    ["points"]=>
    int(77)
  }
```

How can I for example just echo each Team name from this array?

Comment: There is no information about the team name. Just team id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward.

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo $item->team_id;
}
```

Comment: @Evan I don't believe that to be the case. He asked to echo `each` team name (id?) from the array (which I is only shown partially, but would seem to contain 20 objects).

Comment: This was perfect, which is amazing given my terrible explanation. Thank you

Comment: @MikeBrant You're right, I actually was the one to misread this

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHP `json_decode`

```
$obj = json_decode($getData);
$value= $obj->{'team-id'};
```